# Cassandra saving time series for industry data sensors

Tags: cassandra, time-series, plc

I am currently developing a project and researching the best way to retrieve data from industrial factory sensors connected to PLCs (the controller of the machinery in a factory for example the control motors, speeds, switches... ).

I will explain the objective to achieve and I think my case could be extrapolated to so much different types of industries:

1. I have several PLCs that give me a lot of different data values. (Many of these values are only booleans and other are analog values, real type for example.)
2. I will have more than 10.000 sensors in a whole factory.
3. I want to retrieve the data at least every second for the analog values (for example motor rmp, temperature, humidity....).
4. For the digital values the data will be saved with timestamp when a event appears.

I want to use Cassandra with timeseries because it looks the most promising and faster technlogy to do that.

**My question is about storing analog values every second. Is it better to have a schema like:**

> timestamp, sensor1, sensor2, sensor3, sensor4

**and row and group it by parts in the factory or is it better that**

> every sensor has his own table

**?**

The whole system will be developed in Java and it will provide the data to an external company in order to analyse it.

Comment: Any updates since the time you posted this question on how you designed around the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not quite clear what your query is. You mention
"I want to retrieve the data at least every second for the analogic values (for example motor rmp, temperature, humidity....)".

Does that mean you're querying every second for all 10K sensors? Or for a specific sensor, or for a group of sensors? In cassandra, it's vital to know what your query is before looking at data models. If you're looking for 1 second granuality, one option may be to feed incoming data streams to Spark Streaming, and have the Spark Streaming code save to a Cassandra table that suits what you want to query.

As for the options you mention, it's hard to say without knowing the exact nature of your queries. Having one key ronded to the second may be an option - that would mean 10K or so entries per partition, assuming a data rate or 1/s per sensor. Having a table per sensor would be weird, but you may have a partition per sensor with timestamps for each entry. It really depends on your query.

Perhaps if you gave us an example of how you intend to retrieve the data, we can help better?

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. I want to storage the sensor data but I have not created the queries I will apply for.
The only data I know I will query for sure will be the analog values in a graphics like stock tickers (you select time, day, month and you see the graphic) but I dont really know what of this data will be show at the same time or not.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to know a bit about your queries. You mention you'll specify time, day and month...will you also be specifying the sensors or collection of sensors? What's the granularity of time? If it's to the second, and you're not expecting 100s of thousands of events in 2 second window, then ((day, hour, second), sensor_id) *might* be a good primary key. Bu again, without knowing queries, we're throwing in the dark. I'd actually analyse the requirements to see what sort of queries are needed. Query driven modelling is a mindshift, but is vital for cassandra.

Comment: thank you ashic, how we said in spain is like build the house from the roof. 
I need to change my mind and later on I can build a proper system for that. But I confront the problem of we dont know what data will be use later on and this is causing me a problem for develop a db on Cassandra

Comment: it's not necessarily a problem with Cassandra. Even with, say, SQL Server, if you model without any ideas of what your queries are going to be, you'll likely run into performance issues, and very complicated queries. In Cassandra, the move from the conceptual model to the actual physical model is usually quite significant. But at the same time, a well designed SQL database will know what queries it can and cannot support efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that in the end you'll want to query the data both by sensors and by time. There is no reason you wouldn't have two tables and write each data point into both. (Twitter writes each tweet into a different table for each person who follows the tweet!)

Some likely tables you would write are:

```
CREATE TABLE factory_status (
  date timestamp,
  hour int,
  minute int,
  second int,
  sensor_status_map map<uuid, float>
  PRIMARY KEY ((date, hour, minute, second))
)
```

This table would essentially log the status of all sensors in the factory each second. Each partition would contain a snapshot of the factory. This wouldn't be very useful for queries as you couldn't effectively get a range of time (each second would be its own query), but it could be very powerful in doing analytics on the factory and developing a model for failures.

```
CREATE TABLE sensor_status (
  sensor_id uuid,
  date timestamp,
  time timestamp,
  sensor_val float,
  PRIMARY KEY ((sensor_id, date), time)
)
```

This table would essentially log each sensor's output. Each date would be the truncated version of the time. Otherwise the sensor's once per second entry would quickly overwhelm cassandra's column limit. This would make it easy to query the status of a sensor at a particular time or over a period of time.

If you're having trouble designing "from the roof down", feel free to take an iterative approach and add new tables as you find a new query you need to run that doesn't fit the mold of the old queries.

Comment: first of all for this interesting reply. I get you point now. One few question there is any limit when performance decrease for example in number of colums? or like i see in you first approach putting a map in a row will be the easier approach and also so much flexible for me (it is normal to add new sensor data).

Comment: Cassandra handles wide rows very effectively. The number of columns will not impact the speed very much. Querying a subset of the columns is also efficient. There are some streaming issues when the raw amount of data queried gets very large (greater than about 2MB). Assuming a single value or even just a small number of values for each sensor, I would be surprised if you ran into that issue with 10,000 sensors (at 100,000 it might be more of a concern).